# Why is my printList function not working?

Tags: c++, linked-list

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Node
{
    char item;
    Node *next; 
};

void inputChar ( Node * );
void printList (Node *);
char c;


int main()
{

    Node *head;
    head = NULL;
    c = getchar();
    if ( c != '.' )
    {
        head = new Node;
        head->item = c;
        inputChar(head);
    }
    cout << head->item << endl;
    cout << head->next->item << endl;
    printList(head);
    return 0;
}

void inputChar(Node *p)
{
    c = getchar();
    while ( c != '.' )
    {
        p->next = new Node;             
        p->next->item = c;
        p = p->next;
        c = getchar();
    } 
    p->next = new Node; // dot signals end of list              
    p->next->item = c;
}

void printList(Node *p)
{
    if(p = NULL)
        cout << "empty" <<endl;
    else
    {
        while (p->item != '.')
        {
            cout << p->item << endl;
            p = p->next;
        }
    }
}
```

This program takes input from the user one character at a time and places it into a linked list.  *printList* then attempts to print the linked list.  The cout statements immediately before the call to *printList* in *main* work fine but for some reason the *printList* function hangs up in the while loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(p = NULL)
```

That's your problem right there.  It should be

```
if(p == NULL)
```

Comment: Ah shoot.  I'm an amateur hehe.  Thanks!